# Uploading multiple files in Android

Tags: android, service

I have built a service to upload a file in Android. I have started it as foreground service with a notification that I use to show the uploading progress.

Now I want to allow multiple uploads of files, it will be ideal if I can have multiple instances of my service, how ever as I understand it, it's not possible to have multiple instances of a service. What else can I do?

Comment: what protocol is used for upload? Http i presume. so which client or lib wrapper for the http? The various libs offer ways ( thread pools/ async http ) to fire alot of uploads to the same domain and to have them handled per SMP capability of the hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[example here](http://pastebin.com/v4EDq6mr) using android handlers queues and runnables to upload 63 80K files to a cloud service in 3 seconds. The code uses apache httpclient threadpools and a technique for parallelizing and enqueing http requests covered [here](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/)

Those ideas can be adapted to a service that can post runnables to a queue.